# InvalidAlgorithmError in Django REST framework simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Does anybody how to solve this issue?

```
from .backends import TokenBackend
  File "....../envs/jwt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py", line 7, in <module>
    from jwt import InvalidAlgorithmError, InvalidTokenError, algorithms
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidAlgorithmError' from 'jwt' (...../drf-courses/jwt/jwt/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Do not name your package `jwt` as it clashes with the pypi `jwt` package. You also seem to try using an unsupported signing algorithm. Post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @Selcuk I am using default ObtainTokenPairView()

Comment: Can't say anything else without seeing your code. Rename your package first.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you so much mate. It was a naming issue.